# How to remove mipmap folders when generating an android third party client?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created my own Android Client, but when I try to import on my other Android Project I got the following error:

> ic_launcher.png: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.

I'm 100% sure that this is because the client I have created is generating the mipmap folders and when I try to import on my project they conflict with the other mipmap folders. So, erasing the mipmap folders on the project that is trying to import the library solves the issue. However, I want a solution where the client doesn't generate mipmap folders.

Do you guys know how to generate android clients without such folders?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've discovered the problem on how to avoid the mipmap folders when generating an android library. When you want to create a library on Android, I strongly recommend using the Wizard of Android Studio and create a new Library. Doing that, the mipmap folders won't be on your Android Client and you won't have any problem related to what I have described on my question.

I was facing the issue, because I have created an Android Project and then started to convert it to an Android Library. I've done all the steps to convert the Project to an Android Library, however, the mipmap folders were on the library and when I was trying to import the library to my project, the mipmap folders started to conflict to each other.